# How to express python callable type without determining return type?

Tags: python, type-hinting, python-typing

I have a function which returns another function, but the return type of returned function is not clear. To express function return type we can use `Callable[[], ReturnType]`, and to not emphasize on arguments we can do this `Callable[..., ReturnType]`. But I want this `ReturnType` to not be determined.

What should I do?

My code is something like this:

```py
def funcA() -> int:
  return 2

def funcB() -> str:
  return 'b'

def f(inp: int) -> Callable[[], X] # <--- what should X be Here?
  return funcA if inp == 0 else funcB
```

Answer (score 7):

In theory, `f` returns either `int` or `str`, so the return type should be [`typing.Union[int, str]`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Union).

If you don't want to specify the return type then you can use [`typing.Any`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Any).